# Showing $\Phi^{-1}(x) = - \Phi^{-1}(1-x)$ for a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, quantile

Let $\Phi$ be the CDF of a normal random variable. Let $x \in (0,1)$. Why do we have
$$\Phi^{-1}(x) = - \Phi^{-1}(1-x)?$$

Comment: To prove this analytically, it is a bit of pesky. At any rate, you have $\Phi(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^x n$ where $n$ is the standard Gaussian kernel. Since $n$ is symmetric, $\Phi(x) = \int\limits_{-x}^\infty n$ and since $n$ integrates to 1, $1 - \Phi(x) = \int\limits_x^\infty n.$  Try using these to prove the equality, you need to prove that $t = -\Phi^{-1}(1 - \Phi(s))$ is the point such that $\Phi(t) = \Phi(s).$

Comment: Actually, it follows much more easily than I thought, since $1 - \Phi(x) = \int\limits_x^\infty n = \Phi(-x),$ then $x = -\Phi^{-1}(1 - \Phi(x))$ as stated. (Call $t = \Phi(x),$ then $x = \Phi^{-1}(t).$)